# Cannt run pdflatex in texstudio

Tags: archlinux, manjaro, tex-live

If i run in terminal sudo pdflatex file.tex it works and compiles but not if i dont add sudo nor use texstudio?

I tryed to add pdflatex to my $PATH:

```
PATH=$PATH:/usr/bin/pdflatex
export PATH
```

but it didnt help.

```
$ sudo which pdflatex
/usr/bin/pdflatex
```

Comment: How did you installed it ?

Comment: i added/edited in the configs of texstudio the pdflatex path "/usr/bin/pdflatex" -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode %.tex worked for me.